# Reviewing for Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Next semester I am enrolling in Differential Equations, and I am worried that I am not as sharp as I used to be in Calculus. I haven't taken a Calculus class since last fall, and since that time I have forgotten a lot of what I know about integration and differentiation.

My question is: can you guys recommend any references for me so that I can get back into the swing of integrating and differentiating? Also, what would you guys recommend I focus on for the course? (it is the first course I will have taken on the subject) I don't know if there are any specific things I will find useful to review for the course, and I really don't want to fall behind because I don't have enough prior knowledge/ practice.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, some "mathematics people" turn their nose up at Khan Academy because it isn't as rigorous as some other outlets.  But if you are just looking to review the techniques of integration and differentiation, going through the Khan Academy Calculus course would be well worth your time.